# InvalidOperationException when calling ResolveReferencePaths on a referenceassembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

In an Asp .Net Core 3 project (new and empty), I'm trying to get all assembly path doing this

```cs
var references = context.CompileLibraries.SelectMany(library => library.ResolveReferencePaths()).ToList();
```

And i'm getting an InvalidOperationException instead of the list of the path. This is happening on the referenceassembly type of library.

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the preserveCompilationReferences parameter to the csproj (inside PropertyGroup)

```
<PreserveCompilationReferences>true</PreserveCompilationReferences>
```